# Create a hyperlink to a different Excel sheet in the same workbook

Tags: python, excel, hyperlink, openpyxl

I'm using the module openpyxl for Python and am trying to create a hyperlink that will take me to a different tab in the same Excel workbook. Doing something similar to the following creates the hyperlink; however, when I click on it, it tells me it can't open the file.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
first_sheet = wb.create_sheet(title='first')
second_sheet = wb.create_sheet(title='second')

first_sheet['A1'] = "hello"
second_sheet['B2'] = "goodbye"

link_from = first_sheet['A1']
link_to = second_sheet['B2'].value

link_from.hyperlink = link_to

wb.save("C:/somepath/workbook.xlsx")
```

I'm assuming the issue lies in the value of 'link_to'; however, I don't know what would need changed or what kind of path I would have to write.

I'm using Python 2.7.6 and Excel 2013.

Comment: Why are you linking to the cell value?  You should link only to the range.

Comment: I removed that, but the only reason was because it worked... (as in it created a hyperlink).  It just doesn't actually take me to the other sheet.

Comment: actually, I'm keeping it in there; if I take out the '.value', I get the error...:
'cannot serialize <Cell second.B2> <type Cell>

Comment: From looking at the source, it appears that `.hyperlink` is only for external references in `openpyxl`.

Comment: well that would be a bummer... do you know of anyway around it?

Comment: Use .Net w/ Interop or VBA.  The problem is there are two properties in a hyperlink object one is `SubAddress` and the other is `Address`.  `SubAddress` is used for internal references and `openpyxl` only writes to the `Address` property.

Comment: I guess that makes sense.  I don't think I'm going to add the hyperlinks, though.  I've added enough external tools as is. Thanks.

Comment: The [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/) module supports hyperlinks to cells within the workbook via the [`write_url()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#write_url) method and the `internal:` URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for hyperlinks in openpyxl is currently extremely rudimentary and largely limited to reading the links in existing files.

Answer (score 27):

I found a way to do it.

Assuming one .xlsx file named '**workbookEx.xlsx**' with two sheets named '**sheet1**' and '**sheet2**' and needing a link from one cell(**A1**) of the '**sheet1**' to another cell(**E5**) of the '**sheet2**':

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(workbookEx.xlsx) 
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("sheet1")

link = "workbookEx.xlsx#sheet2!E5"

ws.cell(row=1, column=1).hyperlink = (link)
```

The secret was the "#", Excel do not shows you but it uses the '#' for same file links, I just had to copy a same file link created in Excel to a Word document to see the '#'.

It is also possible to omit the filename, i.e. to link against a sheet of the active document just use: `_cell.hyperlink = '#sheetName!A1'`.

To name the link you just created, just set the cell value to the desired string: `_cell.value = 'Linkname'`.

Comment: Nice work!  And if you just mean the text you see in the cell containing the hyperlink, just add:      ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "text you want"

Comment: That was exactly what I meant. Thank you, simple and works pretty well.

Comment: If the sheet name has spaces it won't work without quotes*. E.g.: `cell.hyperlink = '#\'my sheet name\'!E5'`
(* I've only tried single quotes, and they work)

Comment: Adding onto @Neofish :  I found I always have to add single quotes around the sheet name.  The reason is if the sheetname looks like a cell address (e.g.:  C60r1 because C60 is a proper cell address), then Excel behind the scenes encases the name with single quotes.  These seems to do no harm when the sheet name does not need the single quotes.

Comment: To have the cell appear as a hyperlink, add `ws.cell(row=1, column=1).style = "Hyperlink"`

Answer (score 4):

As an addendum to Marcus.Luck's answer, if wanting to use Excel's built-in hyperlink function directly, you may need to format as:

`'=HYPERLINK("{}", "{}")'.format(link, "Link Name")`

Without this formatting, the file didn't open for me without needing repair, which removed the cell values when clicking the links.

e.g. `ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = '=HYPERLINK("{}", "{}")'.format(link, "Link Name")`

Comment: that's really excellent. The link doesn't appear underlined, but it works! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another working solution is to use excels built in function [HYPERLINK](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/HYPERLINK-function-333C7CE6-C5AE-4164-9C47-7DE9B76F577F).
It doesn't make the value in the cell into a hyperlink but put a formula in the cell and act like a hyperlink.

```
ws.cell('A1').value = '=HYPERLINK("#sheet2!E5","Link name")'
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answers, it is also useful to format the cell to make it look like the hyperlinks created within Excel. To do this use the Excel style named "Hyperlink", as per example below which also includes using single quotes around sheet names in case they include spaces (as mentioned by Neofish).

```
cell(row, col).value = '=HYPERLINK("#\'{}\'!A1", "{}")'.format(sheet_name_with_spaces, "Link Name")
cell(row, col).style = 'Hyperlink'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import openpyxl as opxl
import pandas as pd
def hyperlinking(New_file_path):
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(New_file_path)
    sheets = xls.sheet_names
    wb = opxl.load_workbook(New_file_path)
    ws = wb.create_sheet("Consolitated_Sheet")
    ws['A1'] = "Sheet_Name"; ws['B1'] = "Active_link"
    for i, j in enumerate(sheets):
        # print('A'+str(i+2) + ' value is: ' + j)
        ws['A' + str(i + 2)] = j
        ws['B' + str(i + 2)].value = '=HYPERLINK("%s", "%s")' % ('#' + str(j) + '!A1', 'Clickhere')
    wb.save(New_file_path)
    wb.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answer doesn't really fit my case (i did not say them wrong :) my excel file is just weird), so i did a little experiment and this code works perfectly for me.

Suggest when sheet "first" cell "A1" clicked we move to sheet "second" cell "A1"

```py
sheet_to_move= 'second'
cell_to_move= 'A1'

first_sheet['A1'].hyperlink.location= f"'{sheet_to_move}'!{cell_to_move}"
first_sheet['A1'].hyperlink.display= f"'{sheet_to_move}'!{cell_to_move}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As a summary of the previous answers. Just now this worked for me:

```
sheet.cell(row=5, column=2).style = 'Hyperlink'
sheet.cell(row=5, column=2).hyperlink = '#Index!C6'
sheet.cell(row=5, column=2).value = 'Back to Index'
```