# How to create a hyperlink from one sheet of an excel document to another excel sheet in the same document with Python?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an excel file, in one of the columns I want to create a link for another sheet in the same excel file. How can I do it?

Comment: What kind of link? Once clicked to jump to the other sheet? or a Cell reference?

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110511/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-to-a-different-excel-sheet-in-the-same-workbook?rq=1)

Comment: My problem got solved. I made a small mistake in my code.Thanks!